# Angular Material importing module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have added Angular Material module like this in material.module.ts file.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

In my code, I have added Material module in **imports** section one time then same time i have added the same module in **exports** section.

So, i want to write code something like this:

```
importsAM = [
 MatFormFieldModule,
 MatSelectModule,
 MatInputModule,
 MatDatepickerModule,
]


 @NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    importsAM 
  ],
  exports: [
   importsAM 
    
  ],
})
```

So, there is any way to write code something like that. or How can i reduce the duplicate code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
...

const modules = [
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatDatepickerModule
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...modules
  ],
  exports: [
    ...modules
  ],
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

If `exports` does not have any other modules, you could also go with  `exports: modules`.